# Local SQL Server can't connect using IP/Hostname other than Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, database, database-connection

I just got DB server from infra team which configured by previous team.
I found out that the SQL Server Database can only be opened using Windows Authentication using installation name like "SQLEXPRESS\SQLEXPRESS"

I am working on this Database in local Database machine.
I am curious, why i can't use the localhost name or even IP to connect to Database even i am on the DB server itself using the SQL Server Management Studio.

[Error when connect using HostName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7xHQ.png)

I have verified the sa account does exist and updated the password.
When i tried connect using IP, it said The system cannot find the file specified.

[Error when connecting using IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaJMr.png)

I have checked the SQL Configuration Manager, all the Client setting has been set to Enabled. Checked the Firewall, it is not set ON for the DB server. SQL DB services are up since i can connect using Windows Authentication.
I tried to PING to either hostname and IP from command prompt, it is connecting successfully and able to resolve the host name.
I have compared the DB setting with other Database which i can connect using DNS/IP, everything looks fine to me.

Appreciate if anyone can advise, what did i miss to check?

Thank you.

Best Regards,
Fanny T

Comment: Have you confirmed that login sa is in 'enabled' state? I could not connect to local server once because sa login was disabled.

Comment: Also make sure, Server Authentication is set to 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode'

Comment: Yes, I have verified these things. sa is in enabled state and Server Authentication is set to SQL Server and WIndows Auth Mode. But still the error persist.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue for one of my servers and solution in this link worked for me. https://serverfault.com/questions/35505/cant-connect-to-sql-server-using-sa-account-what-im-missing. I had to restart sql server services for it to work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

may be you forget to put instance name like :

```
172.38.207.74\SQLExpress
```

or

```
prd-wm-db.___\SQLExpress
```

also make sure protocol Named Pipes and TCP/IP is enabled in your sql server configuration manager.

Comment: I am able to use the IP and hostname in other instance. So in my opinion it should be working as well in this server.

Comment: Just wanted to add that Named Pipes and TCP/IP is already  in enabled state. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I made a good progress.

After executing what suggested in this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/35505/cant-connect-to-sql-server-using-sa-account-what-im-missing) as advised by **AB_87**

```
 ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD='newpassword', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
 GO
 ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
 GO

 EXEC sp_defaultdb 'sa', 'master'
```

I am able to login using "**sa**" but still using the InstanceName SQLEXPRESS\SQLEXPRESS.
This was not happening previously.

I am still trying a way to how to connect using either hostname/IP. Since i need to put this connection string in the application.
Will update again if I found something.

But still appreciate if anyone has some idea.

Thanks again.